# Query on skeleton class of Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

In machine1/folder1, I placed `HelloClient.java` & `HelloInterface.java`
and ran java1.5 compilation:

```
javac HelloClient.java HelloInterface.java
```

In machine2/folder2, I placed `HelloInterface.java` / `Hello.java` / `HelloServer.java` files and ran java 1.5 compilation:

```
 javac *.java` //here `HelloInterface` definition is required by Hello Class only for compilation.
```

stub/skeleton classes also get generated here in machine2.

I copied `Hello_stub.class` in to machine1/folder1

Next, i ran object registry

```
rmiregistry &
```

and started the server which binds the object to that registry.

```
java -Djava.security.policy=policy HelloServer &
```

where the policy file has

```
grant{
     permission  java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

and then ran the client:

```
java HelloClient testing abc
```

My question is:

1) `HelloClient.class` on machine1 is using `Hello_stub.class` when we invoke `hello.say()` from client program to communicate with machine2, 
But am not clear at which instance `Hello_skel.class` on machine 2 is invoked by `HelloServer.class` ? Can you please help me understand this?

2) Coming from socket programming background in C, How do i visualise `socket()`/`connect()` part of client program and `socket()`/`bind()`/`listen()`/`accept()` pasrt of server program in this RMI framework?

I wrote the below interface(HelloInterface.java)

```
import java.rmi.*;
public interface HelloInterface extends Remote{
          public String say(String msg) throws RemoteException;
    }
```

and i wrote the below class(Hello.java) whose object's method will be accessed from remote.

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
public class Hello extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloInterface {
        private String message;
        public Hello(String msg) throws  RemoteException{
               message = msg;
        }

        public String say(String m) throws RemoteException{
               return new StringBuffer(m).reverse().toString();
        } 
}
```

I wrote the Server program(HelloServer.java), which registers the 'Hello' Object with rmiregistry program.

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
public class HelloServer{
       public static void main(String argv[]){
           if(System.getSecurityManager() == null)
                   System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
           try{
                   Naming.rebind("Hello", new Hello("Hello, world!"));
                   System.out.println("Server is running");
              }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Hello server failed: " + e);
              }
       }
}
```

I wrote the client program(HelloClient.java) that invokes remote method 'say'

```
import java.rmi.*;
public class HelloClient {
     public static void main(String argv[]){
           try{
                 if(args.length < 0){
                     System.err.println("usage: java HelloCient string..");
                     System.exit(1);
                  }
                  HelloInterface hello =
                      (HelloInterface)Naming.lookup("//machine2:1099/Hello");
                  for(int i=0; i < args.length; i++)
                         System.out.println(hello.say(argv[i]); 
              }catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println("HelloClient exception: " + e);
              }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// here HelloInterface definition is required by Hello Class only for compilation
```

No. It is also required by `HelloServer` and `HelloClient` for compilation, and it is required at runtime as well, by both the server and the client, and also by the RMI Registry.

> stub/skeleton classes also get generated here in machine2.

No. RMI skeletons have been obsolete since 1998. You didn't generate one at all, unless you used the `rmic` option `-v1.1` or `-vcompat,` and you don't need to use either. You don't even need to use `rmic` itself at all since Java 1.5, if you just add `super(0)` to your `Hello` constructor.

> I copied `Hello_stub.class` in to machine1/folder1

You also need `HelloInterface.class` here.

> HelloClient.class on machine1 is using Hello_stub.class when we invoke hello.say() from client program to communicate with machine2

Correct.

> [I] am not clear at which instance Hello_skel.class on machine 2 is invoked by HelloServer.class

It isn't invoked at all, unless you used `rmic -v1.1,` in which case it is invoked *by RMI* to mediate between the RMI runtime system and the `Hello` object. It doesn't have anything to do with the `HelloServer` class at all.

> Coming from socket programming background in C, How do i visualise socket()/connect() part of client program

RMI creates connections as needed, pools them, and closes them when they've been idle. There is a connection required to call `Naming.lookup(),` and another one to call the remote method.

> and socket()/bind()/listen()/accept() pasrt of server program in this RMI framework?

Exporting a remote object creates a listening socket, or shares one that has already been created by RMI. The RMI runtime system calls `accept(),` works out from the request header which remote object it's for, and calls that remote object via reflection (or the old skeleton) with the arguments in the request, and sends the result or exception if any back to the client.

NB:

1. You don't need a `SecurityManager` or a .policy file or the `-Djava.security.policy` argument unless you're using the RMI codebase feature, and you aren't.
2. I don't see what the `msg` parameter and instance member is for in `Hello.` You aren't using it.
3. You don't really need `HelloServer.` You could put that `main()` method into `Hello.`
4. Your client doesn't call any remote methods on the object it looks up. Presumably you want to add that?

Comment: @EJB 1) HelloInterface definition is required by HelloServer.java, because main() method is calling 'new Hello("Hello, world!")', and Hello class implements that interface, is my understnading correct?

Comment: @Sham Yes. Same for `HelloClient.`

Comment: @EJB 2) super(0) in Hello() constructor avoids using stub and skeleton class. How does it work internally without stub and skeleton?  3) Is v1.1 RMI an older version of RMI?

Comment: @Sham (1) It uses a 'dynamic proxy'. See the preamble to the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObject.` (2) Yes.

Comment: @EJB can i chat with you? i have more queries on dynamic proxy

Comment: No. Read the documentation. You don't need to know anything more than stated there, or here.

Comment: @EJB if we dont use stubclass on client side and skeleton class on serverside, does super(0) creates dynamic proxy on server side machine only? If yes, how does client know that hello.say() method is on machine2, i edited query for client code

Comment: @Sham Obviously not. Constructing the remote object creates a stub which is put into the Registry, and the client gets it from there. That's what the `bind()` and `lookup()` steps are for. The stub knows where it came from, and how to communicate calls with the RMI runtime system there. If you're going to keep asking for a complete explanation of how RMI works under the covers, please don't. Buy my book ;-)

Comment: @EJB Does HelloClient class on machine1 physically get stubclass from machine2 server after running Naming.lookup() in runtime? and Does HelloServer class on machine2 get access to skeleton class after running Naming.rebind() call?

Comment: @EJB When you say: "Exporting a remote object creates a listening socket, or shares one that has already been created by RMI."--- I think this is done by Naming.rebind() calls, then what does 'rmiregistry' internally do?

Comment: @EJB Can you name the book?

Comment: Pitt & McNiff, *java.rmi: The Complete Guide to Remote Method Invocation,* Addison Wesley 2001. Out of print, sad to say, but you can still pick it up second-hand.

Comment: @Sham The RMI Registry is basically just a remote hash table, where `bind()`=`put(),` `lookup()`=`get(),` etc. The socket `listen()` and `bind()` functions are done when exporting the remote object, as I said. Not by `Naming.bind()`, as you said. If you want to argue about it, try elsewhere, I'm really not interested. It's easy enough to test with `netstat.`

Comment: Classes are not moved by RMI at all, unless you're using the codebase feature, which you aren't. `HelloServer` doesn't have anything whatsoever to do with the skeleton class: I've already told you that, and I intensely dislike repeating myself.